# How do Java public/private and static modifiers affect multiple variables declared on one line?

Tags: java, syntax, static, declaration, access-modifiers

Are the following equivalent?

```
private static boolean readAllFiles = false,readAllDirs = false;

private static boolean readAllFiles = false;
private static boolean readAllDirs = false;
```

And if so, do they still have the same modifiers with different values?

```
private static boolean readAllFiles = false,readAllDirs = true;
```

Comment: Quick note - most people consider the second way - the multiple lines - to be the "better" or more correct, as it is easier to read.  The more explicit is usually better, and code file size is usually not an issue (assuming you are following other best practices)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent, regardless of their initial values.

Here is some test code to demonstrate:

```
public class TestClass
{
  private static boolean readAllFiles = false,readAllDirs = true;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //these two would result in COMPILE error if both vars were not static
    System.out.println("readAllFiles: " + readAllFiles);
    System.out.println("readAllDirs: " + readAllDirs);
  }
}
```

---

```
public final class TestClass2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //these two DO result in COMPILE error, because both vars are private
    System.out.println("TestClass.readAllFiles: " + TestClass.readAllFiles);
    System.out.println("TestClass.readAllDirs: " + TestClass.readAllDirs);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

They are all equivalent.

Your last statement:

```
private static boolean readAllFiles = false,readAllDirs = true;
```

is equivalent to:

```
private static boolean readAllFiles = false;
private static boolean readAllDirs = true;
```